# WPF exception when designing components

Tags: wpf, unhandled-exception

From nowhere my wpf project started to show this unhandled exception:

```
GenericArguments[0], 'T', on 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcObjectExtender`1[TSfcInstance]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TSfcInstance'.
```

Does anyone know what this means and how to fix it?
This only happens when im creating a new usercontrol or window, on runtime it works good. This is just annoying because i cant see the design while adding new components..

Thanks